# How can I check if a value is NULL in PostgreSQL while quoting it?

Tags: sql, c, postgresql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT choice, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM Vote, Person
WHERE Vote.pid = Person.pid AND (Person.city = '%s' OR %s IS NULL) <-----
GROUP BY choice
ORDER BY c DESC, choice
```

I've included the `Person.city = '%s' OR %s IS NULL` part so that, if the parameter is `NULL`, the query will include all cities. This query works fine when the parameter is `NULL`, but when I enter a non-`NULL` value, say Paris, I get this error:

> Error: column "Paris" does not exist at character 104

And as far as I can tell, this error happens because `%s` isn't quoted. But when I do quote it, if `%s` is NULL, then `'%s' IS NULL` doesn't evaluate to true.

How can I check I check if `%s` is `NULL` when it's quoted?

Comment: Daniel... You're comparing the value you expect in the column as the column name. See my answer for the correct statement.

Comment: What happens client-side to these `%s`? This query is simply run through `sprintf` with the raw values and then passed to `PQexec`?

Comment: Yes - it's a homework assignment and we can assume that the values are valid.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try:

```
SELECT choice, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM Vote join
     Person
     on Vote.pid = Person.pid 
WHERE (Person.city = '%s' OR '%s' = 'NULL') 
GROUP BY choice
ORDER BY c DESC, choice;
```

You won't be able to search explicitly for "NULL", but that might be a small price to pay.

Note I also changed the join syntax to use explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: Is this the only solution? It seems sort of hacky, and it doesn't address the core problem of not being able to check if a parameter is NULL.

Comment: @Daniel . . . I think more typically `NULL` wouldn't be used.  Instead, a blank string would be and `person.city = '%s' or '%s' = ''` reads fine.

Answer (score 0):

if your variable is not NULL your query should be:

```sql
SELECT choice, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM Vote as V join
     Person as P
     on V.pid = P.pid 
WHERE P.city = '%s'
GROUP BY choice
ORDER BY c DESC, choice;
```

... and if %s is NULL:

```sql
SELECT choice, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM Vote as V join
     Person as P
     on V.pid = P.pid 
GROUP BY choice
ORDER BY c DESC, choice;
```

Definitely not the most terse way, but certainly the clearest.

I originally misunderstood the question and for that I apologise. Hope that helps...

Comment: Your column is city not the value you're passing it. The value you're passing should never be null.

Comment: This is part of a C method that accepts a `char*` city parameter, which can be NULL. `P.city` is never `NULL` and your query isn't equivalent to the query in my question.

Comment: And as I said, the query does work when `%s` is NULL. It doesn't work when it's not NULL.

Comment: You should change your query to test `P.city is not NULL` when the variable passed in is blank then.

Comment: I don't understand your comment - are you saying I should write a separate query when the variable is NULL?

Comment: In response to your edit: the solution of writing two separate queries is an obvious one, but my question is asking if there's a way to do it in a single query. Or in a more concise manner, I'm asking how you can check if a parameter is NULL.

Comment: I'd check that in your client code. When you build the statement, you can have, something like, `SELECT choice, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM Vote as V join
     Person as P
     on V.pid = P.pid (?param != null : "WHERE p.city = '%s'" : "") GROUP BY choice, ORDER BY c DESC, choice;` Do note, my C knowledge is about 15 years out of date.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use **prepared statements** instead. Detailed instructions for `C` in this related answer:
[Passing C variables into SQL command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071764/passing-c-variables-into-sql-command/23072368#23072368)

Then you pass values as *values* instead of trying string concatenation, which also opens you up to *SQL injection*.

Your query could look like this (simplified with explicit `JOIN` syntax and positional parameters in `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`) :

```
SELECT v.choice, count(*) AS c
FROM   vote v
JOIN   person p USING (pid)
WHERE (p.city = $1 OR $1 IS NULL)
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 2 DESC, 1;
```

The parentheses are not needed here - only if you add more conditions since `AND` binds before `OR`.

Or you create a PL/pgSQL function that handles the `NULL` case in a smarter way. I wrote a detailed related answer just yesterday:
[How to remove conditions from WHERE clause if parameters are NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23386078/postgresql-function-how-to-remove-and-condition-if-parameter-is-null/23392859#23392859)

If referential integrity is guaranteed (enforced by a foreign key constraint) and *every* vote has a related person, simplify the function call in case of a `NULL` value:

```
SELECT v.choice, count(*) AS c
FROM   vote v
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 2 DESC, 1;
```